# Assign an oracle date to an SSIS variable

Tags: sql, ssis, odbc

I am trying select a date from an Oracle DB *(1 row result)* and assign its value to an SSIS variable. I tried to convert it `to_char` (which would also work great to me) but I still get an error `"SSIS value does not fall within the expected range"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was about the name of the `Result Name` from whatever I was using to '1'. The helpful post that solve my problem is: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129106/ssis-odbc-mapping-result-set-columns-to-variables-returns-error-value-does-not

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to ensure your SSIS variable is of type String.

I expect you'll still need to convert the Oracle date to a string data type with the `to_char` method but I would have to test and don't have an Oracle instance I can test against.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the to_char method possibly helped as it would be pointless to try handle a date between oracle and microsoft at the moment that I just wanted the string